# SolidColorBrush перекрывает элементы

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

Помогите разобраться с шаблоном.

```
<ResourceDictionary  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  mc:Ignorable="d"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008">

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightBackground" Color="#2D2D30"/>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource LightBackground}"/>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

При запуске решения в дебагере VS 2017 эта конструкция почему-то перекрывает все элементы (происходит заливка цветом поверх всех элементов), а при запуске скомпилированного exe-файла все нормально. В визуальном дизайнере VS так же все в норме.

Comment: А можно самодостаточный пример, что бы мы могли проверить это?

Comment: [drive.google.com](https://drive.google.com/file/d/195x9Y12oWfrcjb6X3n3UaRYlnkGcPul5/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: У меня не воспроизводится

Comment: @АндрейNOP странно... У меня воспроизводится...

Comment: Возможно баг в VS, попробуйте обновиться до самой последней

Comment: @АндрейNOP я запускал на последней версии. После запуска дебагера кнопка появляется на мгновение и закрашивается, как и указал автор.

Comment: @XelaNimed Ага, удалось воспроизвести, у меня были отключены runtime tools, если их включить — баг проявляется. Ну это точно баг в VS, надо слать репорт в MS

Comment: Если указать стилю ключ и в самом контроле выбирать стиль по этому ключу, то работает нормально

Answer (score 0):

Не могу объяснить с чем связано такое поведение, вполне возможно, что это баг (поправьте меня пожалуйста, если я не прав).
Для решения проблемы в вашем конкретном примере закомментируйте или удалите `Style` и укажите свойство `Background` непосредственно в `Grid`:

Dictionary1.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1">
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightBackground" Color="#2D2D30" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid ShowGridLines="True" Background="{DynamicResource LightBackground}">
        <Button Width="200" Height="100" Content="Button"  />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Такое решение не имеет смысла же

Comment: @АндрейNOP поясните, пожалуйста, почему?

Comment: Потому что автору нужен стиль, со всеми его плюшками, наследованием и прочим, ну и приоритет значений для свойств зависимости есть, соответственно это решение не эквивалентно тому что в вопросе.

Comment: @АндрейNOP пусть автор и решает, что ему нужно, а я не претендую на истину в последней инстанции. Я предложил своё решение, а Вы предложите Ваше.